# How to get RSS feeds into Gmail

Tags: gmail, rss

Is there an easy way (say, a bookmarklet) that, whenever I see a feed, I can subscribe to it so that updates will go into my Gmail?

Comment: Do you mean you'd like it to update your Gmail or Google Reader ?

Answer (score 3):

You could use http://blogtrottr.com/ - just paste the RSS url and Your email address and click the confirmation.

Comment: The free tier includes ads.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the official Google reader bookmarklet;

[Share anything with a bookmarklet](http://googlereader.blogspot.com/2008/05/share-anything-anytime-anywhere.html)

And add the [Reader Gadget](http://www.google.co.uk/ig/directory?type=gadgets&url=www.google.com/ig/modules/reader.xml) to your Gmail sidebar.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Since the answer was written, Google Reader was discontinued on 1st July 2013. See https://www.google.com/reader/about/ and https://googleblog.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/a-second-spring-of-cleaning.html

Answer (score 1):

[Feedpostal.com](http://www.feedpostal.com) lets you enter a RSS feed and will then send you daily, weekly or monthly updated depending on your settings.

Comment: Feedpostal has been shut down

Answer (score -3):

I just added Chrome extension RSS Feed Reader 5.3.9. Easy to add. Working great so far.

Comment: A link to the extension would make this a better answer.